# Why is this site called "Writing" but still referred to as "Writers" at Area 51?

Tags: discussion, site-name

First, my apologies, as I'm not certain if this question belongs here or at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) itself.

After joining this site, and contributing to it briefly, I noticed that it was still in beta. Also after joining, I discovered Area 51.

I tried searching Area 51 for "Writing," but was unable to find the site. Instead, I found a site called "[Writers.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1623/writers)" I thought that was odd, since there shouldn't be two different sites with the same topic.

Only after clicking the "Visit the site now!" link presented in Area 51's entry for "Writers" did I discover that the two sites are the same.

According to [this](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/this-site-is-now-writing), the name of this site was changed recently. However, it's still listed by its old name at Area 51.

Shouldn't the name of the Area 51 entry be updated to reflect this name change?

Comment: Yes, the site was recently renamed. Site renames don't happen often, so you might have uncovered a missed step somewhere.

Comment: I added a link to the relevant page on Area 51. Feel free to roll back the edit if you disagree strongly, or edit further as you see fit.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks. I made a slight tweak, but it was a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Area 51 doesn't update when sites are renamed, unfortunately. Community Building was renamed from Moderators years ago but A51 still shows the original name.